# How to snoop on "docker pull" requests from Docker for Mac while it's querying a local registry running on macOS?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

(I'm using Docker for Mac Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) which has docker-engine 18.09.2.)

I'm trying to do this:

- run a docker-registry process directly on my mac on port 8080 (it's not really docker-registry, but something that looks like registry, so it shouldn't matter) without HTTPS
- run a [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on my mac directly on port 5000 (to intercept requests)
- configure docker-engine to use mitmproxy so I can snoop on the requests
- initiate a `docker pull` to my local registry so triggers some requests on my registry which I can monitor on mitmproxy.

### Situation 1: no proxy set on docker-engine

So as I said earlier, I have a server that mimics the docker-registry v2 API running directly on my MacOS on port 8080. So I added `host.docker.internal:8080` as an insecure registry:

[image: screenshot]

Everything works (docker-engine can hit my local registry) fine if I **don't** set a proxy for docker-engine. 
For example, I can do `docker pull host.docker.internal:8080/busybox` and the requests come to my proxy:

[image: screenshot]

### Situation 2: set proxy for docker-engine, pull image from docker hub

When I point the docker-engine to mitmproxy (`host.docker.internal:5000`) and do a `docker pull library/mysql`, that works fine too (I can see the requests made to index.docker.io)

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

### Situation 3: set proxy for docker-engine, pull image from docker hub

So when I combine Situation #1+#2, which is pointing docker-engine to mitmproxy on my laptop as a proxy AND then trying to use `docker pull host.docker.internal:8080/busybox` which has worked before, **it is failing**:

> Server connection to ('host.docker.internal', 8080) failed: Error connecting to "host.docker.internal": [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

[image: screenshot]

The error my proxy sees is that it cannot find `host.docker.internal`. I can't tell if this is because mitmproxy is running on my Mac host OS (and not inside docker VM) and that's why it can't resolve the host.

I'm basically not able to use mitmproxy (on my Mac host OS) to snoop on docker-engine requests as well as run a registry (on my Mac host OS) at the same time.

I tried moving the registry into a container too and changed the hostname to `gateway.docker.internal`, but no luck there either.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal` to your mac's `/etc/hosts`?
It seems to work for me.

- The Docker VM resolves `host.docker.internal:5000` to `192.168.65.2:5000` which connects it to the mitm proxy runnning on the Mac,
- The mitm proxy doesn't know how to resolve `host.docker.internal`, hence the `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error,
- By adding the entry to `/etc/hosts`, you tell mitm to actually connect to the localhost to reach the registry.

Comment: This has made progress! Then I started getting TLS issues (`Cannot establish TLS with host.docker.internal:8080 (sni: host.docker.internal): TlsException("SSL handshake error: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')])")`. At this point I realized the request was still going to the `https://` of my insecure registry. Removing the mitmproxy address from "HTTPS Proxy" setting of Docker for Desktop has mitigated this, so it successfully fell back to using `http://host.docker.internal:5000`. Thanks.